# I need a user on an XP machine that has no option but running a single program and logging off

Tags: windows-xp, limited-user-account

I want to set up a particular user account on a WinXP Pro computer (not part of adomain) who's start menu only has a web browser and the ***Log Off*** / ***Turn Off Computer*** buttons. I played around with gpedit.msc but everything I did there seemed to apply to all the users. Can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Group Policies in Registry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms815238.aspx) is a solution for you. Using policies you can disable nearly everything for the particular user.
The link is for Win 2k, but the layout and semantics are the same for XP. XP has a bit more options to disable, though.

Comment: I tried this but it looks like it's making the change for all the users. How can I limit this to only my "user" user account?

Comment: use not LOCAL_MACHINE key but CURRENT_USER key while you are logged as this user.

Comment: The link above said _"To change the value of entries in this table, use Group Policy. Do not edit the registry."_ So I used gpedit.msc. I suppose that doesn't interface into just a single user's account?

Comment: The link said. But you can do. believe me )